# Macro to automatically delete row with the word "total"

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I need help on a macro to automatically delete a whole row with the word "total". There is number next to the total, and I want to delete the whole row. Issue is, every week the name changes, hence I need it to be dynamic. Attached is my code example.

```
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$60").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "FR083 Total", "FR087 Total", "FR088 Total", "FR089 Total", "FR091 Total", _
        "FR092 Total", "FR093 Total", "FR097 Total", "FR098 Total"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Kindly help on this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.EntireRow property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144123)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.SpecialCells method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144203)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteTotalRow()
    Dim c As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        With .Range("$C$1:$C$60")
            ' Filter the cells contain `total`
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*total*", Operator:=xlAnd
            ' Get the visible cells
            Set c = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                ' Delete the whole rows
                c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
        ' Show all data
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows.Count` needs to become `.Rows.Count`. And some nit-picking: when referencing a smaller range using a bigger range, you don't want to go out of the 'bounds' of the bigger one (if you can help it) i.e. if the range was `.Columns("C")`, `.Offset(1)` would raise an error i.e. it is safer (more accurate) to use `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Rows Matching a Wild Character Pattern Using AutoFilter

**Before**

[image]

**After `Select`**

[image]

**After `Delete`**

[image]

- It is assumed that the data is in table format (no empty rows or columns with one row of headers) and starts in `A1` (`CurrentRegion`) as illustrated in the screenshots.
- If that's not the case, use `Set rg = ws.UsedRange`. If you don't have data in column `A`, use `2`, or in column `B`, use `1` instead of `3`.
- When done testing, replace the `Select` part with the `Delete` part.

```vb
Sub DeleteTotalRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        
    rg.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="FR???? Total"
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Select ' vrg.Delete xlShiftUp '
       
End Sub
```